# Electron after minimize app show a bubble alwaysOnTop and draggable

Tags: electron

I tried to search in the Electron documentation, but I did not find anything similar to what I need to do, I leave an quick image, to show my requirement.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZeBQ.jpg
In summary is, once minimized the application, I need to show a bubble, with an icon and text, with the option alwaysOnTop and can move around the screen. If I click on the bubble, the application is maximized.

if someone has already developed something similar or has some idea of how to look for this, I appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the bubble you can use this function to check if its minimized

```
    if(!win.isMaximized()) {
    // Show your bubble
}
```

then  implement a function to your bubble and when you click it send an ipc render and use the function to show the mainWindow again.

```
mainWindow.restore()
```

If you want it to be full screen you can add

```
mainWindow.maximize();
```